# Проявка блока Div при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, html

Есть код для проявки при прокрутке топ блока с телефонами, нужно чтобы он появлялся при прокрутке, содержимое меняется из-за скрипта js, каким образом можно исправить?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var bo = $(this).scrollTop();
     var a = $("#overnavbar").css('opacity')
     $("#overnavbar").html(bo);
     if (bo >= 200 && a == 0) {
       $("#overnavbar").stop().animate({
         'opacity': '1'
       }, 500)
     };
     if (bo < 200 && a == 1) {
       $("#overnavbar").stop().animate({
         'opacity': '0'
       }, 500)
     };
   })
 })
```

```css
#navbar {
  width: 1165px;
}
#overnavbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(72, 172, 67, .95);
  display: none;
  z-index: 1100;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#navlogo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#navtel {
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-left: 1px solid #319135;
}
#navtel div {
  padding: 0 16px 0 42px;
  border-left: 1px solid #6ec767;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#navbasket {
  border-left: 1px solid #319135;
  border-right: 1px solid #6ec767;
  float: right;
}
#navlogo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 70px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #6ec767;
}
#navbar #navtel a {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="overnavbar" style="display: block;">
  <a id="navlogo" href="/">
    <img src="dop/top/logo.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <div id="navtel">
    <div>
      Заказать по телефонам: &nbsp 8 (495) 946 97 92,&nbsp 8 (800) 775 11 82
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#overnavbar").html(bo);`??? уберите эту строчку и почитайте  - https://api.jquery.com/html/